# How is a homography calculated?

Tags: opencv, geometry, computer-vision

I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding the workings of plane to plane homography. In particular I would like to know how the opencv method works.

Is it like ray tracing? How does a homogeneous coordinate differ from a scale*vector?

Everything I read talks like you already know what they're talking about, so it's hard to grasp!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV Homography, Transform a point, what is this code doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275567/opencv-homography-transform-a-point-what-is-this-code-doing)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Googling `homography estimation` returns this as the first link (at least to me):
http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf. And definitely this is a poor description and a lot has been omitted. If you want to learn these concepts reading a good book like [`Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518) would be far better than reading some short articles. Often these short articles have several serious mistakes, so be careful.

In short, a cost function is defined and the parameters (the elements of the homography matrix) that minimize this cost function are the answer we are looking for. A meaningful cost function is geometric, that is, it has a geometric interpretation. For the homography case, we want to find H such that by transforming points from one image to the other the distance between all the points and their correspondences be minimum. This geometric function is nonlinear, that means: 1-an iterative method should be used to solve it, in general, 2-an initial starting point is required for the iterative method. Here, algebraic cost functions enter. These cost functions have no meaningful/geometric interpretation. Often designing them is more of an art, and for a problem usually you can find several algebraic cost functions with different properties. The benefit of algebraic costs is that they lead to linear optimization problems, hence a closed form solution for them exists (that is a one shot /non-iterative method). But the downside is that the found solution is not optimal. Therefore, the general approach is to first optimize an algebraic cost and then use the found solution as starting point for an iterative geometric optimization. Now if you google for these cost functions for homography you will find how usually these are defined.

In case you want to know what method is used in OpenCV simply need to have a look at the code:
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp#L81
This is the algebraic function, DLT, defined in the mentioned book, if you google `homography DLT` should find some relevant documents. And then here:
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp#L165
An iterative procedure minimizes the geometric cost function.It seems the Gauss-Newton method is implemented:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

All the above discussion assumes you have correspondences between two images. If some points are matched to incorrect points in the other image, then you have got outliers, and the results of the mentioned methods would be completely off. Robust (against outliers) methods enter here. OpenCV gives you two options: 1.RANSAC 2.LMeDS. Google is your friend here.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question we need to address 4 different questions:

```
1. Define homography.
2. See what happens when noise or outliers are present.
3. Find an approximate solution.
4. Refine it.
```

---

1. Homography in a 3x3 matrix that maps 2D points. The mapping is linear in homogeneous coordinates: [x2, y2, 1]’ ~ H * [x1, y1, 1]’, where ‘ means transpose (to write column vectors as rows) and ~ means that the mapping is up to scale. It is easier to see in Cartesian coordinates (multiplying nominator and denominator by the same factor doesn’t change the result)

   x2 = (h11*x1 + h12*y1 + h13)/(h31*x1 + h32*y1 + h33)

   y2 = (h21*x1 + h22*y1 + h23)/(h31*x1 + h32*y1 + h33)

   You can see that in Cartesian coordinates the mapping is non-linear, but for now just keep this in mind.
2. We can easily solve a former set of linear equations in Homogeneous coordinates using least squares linear algebra methods (see DLT - Direct Linear Transform) but this unfortunately only minimizes an algebraic error in homography parameters. People care more about another kind of error - namely the error that shifts points around in Cartesian coordinate systems. If there is no noise and no outliers two erros can be identical. However the presence of noise requires us to minimize the residuals in Cartesian coordinates (residuals are just squared differences between the left and right sides of Cartesian equations). On top of that, a presence of outliers requires us to use a Robust method such as RANSAC. It selects the best set of inliers and rejects a few outliers to make sure they don’t contaminate our solution.
3. Since RANSAC finds correct inliers by random trial and error method over many iterations we need  a really fast way to compute homography and this would be a linear approximation that minimizes parameters' error (wrong metrics) but otherwise is close enough to the final solution (that minimizes squared point coordinate residuals - a right metrics). We use a linear solution as a guess for further non-linear optimization;
4. The final step is to use our initial guess (solution of linear system that minimized Homography parameters) in solving non-linear equations (that minimize a sum of squared pixel errors). The reason to use squared residuals instead of their absolute values, for example, is because in Gaussian formula (describes noise) we have a squared exponent exp(x-mu)^2, so (skipping some probability formulas) maximum likelihood solutions requires squared residuals.

In order to perform a non-linear optimization one typically employs a Levenberg-Marquardt method. But in the first approximation one can just use a gradient descent (note that gradient points uphill but we are looking for a minimum thus we go against it, hence a minus sign below). In a nutshell, we go through a set of iterations 1..t..N  selecting homography parameters at iteration t as param(t) = param(t-1) - k * gradient, where gradient = d_cost/d_param.

Bonus material: to further minimize the noise in your homography you can try a few tricks: reduce a search space for points (start tracking your points); use different features (lines, conics, etc. that are also transformed by homography but possibly have a higher SNR); reject impossible homographs to speed up RANSAC (e.g. those that correspond to ‘impossible’ point movements); use low pass filter for small changes in Homographies that may be attributed to noise.