# Once I get the Homography Matrix from OpenCV and Visual Studio 2010, How I use it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, homography

I have calculated the Homography Matrix using OpenCV and Visual Studio. I have used the basic example of this topic. How should I apply that matrix?...

Comment: ...to achieve what? Also, are you using C++?

Comment: you post multiply it by a 3x1 vector [x,y,1] the result will be a 3x1 vector [c*x', c*y', c].  x' and y' will be in your new coordinate space

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Yes I'm using C++.

Comment: @Hammer Ok, thank you for answer, I get a vector like this: [h11x+h12y+h13, h21x+h22y+h23, h31x+h32y+h33] where h11..h33 are the values that I got from OpenCV. As I know (x' = Hx) so [x', y', 1] = [h11x+h12y+h13, h21x+h22y+h23, h31x+h32y+h33], right?... That means that I need to get every pixel in my image (x,y) and representing it as (x,y,1) then multiply it for H and I will get the new position of that pixel... Am I correct?... Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for my can't post a comment with limited reputation.)

Yes, @Hammer and you are right. As mentioned in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070411/what-do-the-elements-in-a-homography-matrix-mean):

```
/w'x'\   /H11 H12 H13\ /x\
|w'y'| = |H21 H22 H23|*|y|
\w'  /   \ 0   0   1 / \1/
```

totally 7 parameters.

Once you've get the homography matrix H, apply the calculation to each appended vector [x,y,1]T.