# Image Alignment of Multispectral Images Fails with ECC

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I am trying to align an RGB image with an IR image (single channel).
The goal is to create a 4 channel image R,G,B,IR.
In order to do this, I am using  `cv2.findTransformECC` as described in [this very neat guide](https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/). The code is unchanged for now, except for line 13 where the Motion is set to Euclidian because I want to handle rotations in the future. I am using Python.

In order to verify the workings of the software, I used the images from the guide. It worked well so I wanted to correlate satellite images from multiple spectra as described above. Unfortunately, I ran into problems here.

Sometimes the algorithm converged (after ages) and sometimes it immediately crashed because it cant converge and other times it "finds" a solution that is clearly wrong. Attached you find two images that, from a human perspective, are easy to match, but the algorithm fails. The images are not rotated in any way, they are just not the exact same image (check the borders), so a translational motion is expected. Images are of Lake Neusiedlersee in Austria, the source is Sentinelhub.

Edit: With "sometimes" I refer to using different images from Sentinel. One pair of images has consistently the same outcome.

[image: "Neusieldersee" in NIR, Data from Sentinel]
[image: "Neusieldersee" in RGB, Data from Sentinel]

I know that ECC is not feature-based which might pose a problem here.

I have also read that it is somewhat dependent on the initial warp matrix.

My questions are:

1. Am I using `cv2.findTransformECC` wrong?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. Should I try to "Monte-Carlo" the initial matrices until it converges? (This feels wrong)
4. Do you suggest using a feature-based algorithm?
5. If so, is there one available or would I have to implement this myself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may try [Feature Based Image Alignment](https://learnopencv.com/feature-based-image-alignment-using-opencv-c-python/).

Comment: Thanks @Rotem for your comment. I did that since the morning and it fails miserably... I mean miserably! It is absolutely stunning to me how bad it does. I will open another question about how and why SIFT is not able to detect and correlate the features which are clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you suggest using a feature-based algorithm?

Sure.
There are [many feature detections algorithms](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html).
I generally choose SIFT because it provides good matching results and the runtime is feasibly fast.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# read the images
ir = cv.imread('ir.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
rgb = cv.imread('rgb.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

descriptor = cv.SIFT.create()
matcher = cv.FlannBasedMatcher()

# get features from images
kps_ir, desc_ir = descriptor.detectAndCompute(ir, mask=None)
gray = cv.cvtColor(rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kps_color, desc_color = descriptor.detectAndCompute(gray, mask=None)

# find the corresponding point pairs
if (desc_ir is not None and desc_color is not None and len(desc_ir) >=2 and len(desc_color) >= 2):
    rawMatch = matcher.knnMatch(desc_color, desc_ir, k=2)
matches = []
# ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
ratio = 0.75
for m in rawMatch:
    if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
        matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))

# convert keypoints to points
pts_ir, pts_color = [], []
for id_ir, id_color in matches:
    pts_ir.append(kps_ir[id_ir].pt)
    pts_color.append(kps_color[id_color].pt)
pts_ir = np.array(pts_ir, dtype=np.float32)
pts_color = np.array(pts_color, dtype=np.float32)

# compute homography
if len(matches) > 4:
    H, status = cv.findHomography(pts_ir, pts_color, cv.RANSAC)

warped = cv.warpPerspective(ir, H, (rgb.shape[1], rgb.shape[0]))
warped = cv.cvtColor(warped, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# visualize the result
winname = 'result'
cv.namedWindow(winname, cv.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
alpha = 5
# res = cv.addWeighted(rgb, 0.5, warped, 0.5, 0)
res = None
def onChange(alpha):
    global rgb, warped, res, winname
    res = cv.addWeighted(rgb, alpha/10, warped, 1 - alpha/10, 0)
    cv.imshow(winname, res)
onChange(alpha)
cv.createTrackbar('alpha', winname, alpha, 10, onChange)
cv.imshow(winname, res)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyWindow(winname)
```

Result (alpha=8)

[image: result with alpha=8]

**Edit:** It seems like SIFT is not the best option as it fails for some other examples. [Example images are in another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256426/sift-failing-to-correlate-clearly-correlated-images)

In this case, I suggest using SURF.
It is a patented algorithm, so it does not come with the latest OpenCV PIP installations.
You can install previous versions of OpenCV or build it from source.

```
descriptor = cv.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
```

Result (alpha=8)

[image: SURF homography result]

**Edit2:** It is now clear that the key to achieve this task is to choose the correct feature descriptor. As a final note, I suggest choosing the appropriate [motion model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436686/12447766). Affine transform fits better than homography in this case.

```
H, _ = cv.estimateAffine2D(pts_ir, pts_color)
H = np.vstack((H, [0, 0, 1]))
```

Affine transform result:

[image: SURF affine result]

Comment: Hi Burak, thanks for your reply, while you where answering I already wrote my own matching using SIFT (I used an example tbf) and while it seems to work for this one pair of images (by pure chance) it dose not work for others and I am kind of stunned on how SIFT can fail here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256426/sift-failing-to-correlate-clearly-correlated-images

Check out the new thread for the results. Your code has the same problem like the things i descirbed in the other thread. It also can not match the other images.

Comment: @Clex I looked at the new post but there are no images to try the code. Can you edit both posts with more examples?

Comment: thanks for the input, I added two images and also a tutorial on how you can get your own.